# javascript .replace a html tag does not replace

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace some html but the replace is not taking place. I am using the javascript `.replace` and from what I can see I am using it right.

```
content.replace('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">', '<style>html{background-color: blue;}<\/style>');
```

Comment: The `.replace()` function returns the resulting value. It does not modify the original string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strings `replace()` method returns a new string with the new value. It **doesn't** modify the original string.

Here is a simple example:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.replace("World", "Foo");

console.log(str);  // prints Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$('[href="style.css"]').prepend("html{background-color: blue;}");
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated the replace doesn't modify the original string.

Try the below example,

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

[Info here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)